# Remove text file using Oracle Forms

Tags: file, oracleforms, oracle9i

I tried to remove text file in Oracle Forms 6i (DB 9i) using TEXT_IO Package (TEXT_IO.FREMOVE('C:\out_file.txt')).

But I encountered this error:

> FREMOVE MUST BE DECLARED!

How can I fix this problem.

#### My Code:

```
DECLARE
outf TEXT_IO.file_type;
...
BEGIN
outf := TEXT_IO.FOpen('C:\out_file.txt', 'w');
...
IF condition THEN
RAISE remove_file;

EXCEPTION
WHEN remove_file THEN
TEXT_IO.FCLOSE('C:/out_file.txt');
TEXT_IO.FREMOVE('C:/out_file.txt');
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function `Text_IO.FREMOVE` in Oracle Forms 6i. Use d2kwutil.pll and `Win_Api_Utility.Delete_File` or use operating system command using `HOST` built in:

```
HOST('del c:\out_file.txt');
```

Comment: Host sentence does not work. I mean: it's executed but with no effect and no error. So the only way to get the file deleted is using win_api_utility or deleting it outside the form.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: needed to delete a file I was using only to create a directory if directory didn't exist previously. TEXT_IO doesn't have any option, and I didn't want to add d2kwutil to my form. I ended up with this:

```
DECLARE
    v_texto varchar2(3200);
    v_templatePath varchar2(256); v_testFile varchar2(256); v_reportFile varchar2(256);
BEGIN
    --First part: copy file to dest directory. If directory does not exist, xcopy creates it
    v_templatePath := '\\server\reports\templates\';
    v_testFile := 'test.txt';
    v_reportFile := '\\server\reports\<folder_with_date>\test.txt';
    v_texto := 'XCOPY '||v_templatePath||v_testFile||' '||v_reportFile || '* /Y';
    message(v_texto); --so you can see what is going to be executed
    HOST(v_texto, NO_SCREEN); 

    --Second part: delete dummy file
    v_texto := 'cmd /C DEL '||v_reportFile;
    message(v_texto);
    host (v_texto);
    EXIT_FORM(NO_VALIDATE);
END;
```